# Automatically add SQL datetime using SqlBulkCopy with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I am using a `SqlBulkCopy` command to enter data into a sql table. I have the first column which is `CreatedDate`, I set the Default Value or Binding to `getdate()` without quotes. However, it appears that when `bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);` is called the following error is thrown:

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be
>   converted to type datetime of the specified target column.

The Inner Exception is

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime.

I have set the Default Value or Binding for the `CreatedDate` columns to `getdate()`. Does this automatically insert the current date and time into the column when the `SqlBulkCopy` command is executed?

Do I need to add the column `CreatedDate` to the `DataTable`? If I have columns that automatically get inserted do I need to map them or add them? If so, how would you add or map a column of the SQL data type `datetime`?

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var sessionId = Guid.NewGuid();

var table = new DataTable(); // create the datatable

table.Columns.Add("location", typeof (string));
table.Columns.Add("product_name", typeof (string));
table.Columns.Add("product_id", typeof (string));
table.Columns.Add("product_price", typeof (string));
table.Columns.Add("session_id", typeof (string));

foreach (var pair in idsAndPrices) // then loop all dictionary entries and add the rows
{
    table.Rows.Add(location, productName, pair.Key, pair.Value, sessionId);
}

using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.ProductInventory";
    conn.Open();
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table); // write to database
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: you could add a datetime column to your table. The standard SQL datetime format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. So you can get the current datetime in .net by using `DateTime.now` . Then you can parse that datetime using string.format like so `string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.now)` This formatted datetime can then be entered into the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the order of rows in the database and they had been changed. In order to fix this I implemented `SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping` to make sure the column names were aligned before calling `bulkCopy.WriteToServer();` The 'CreatedDate' column in the database automatically populated the table when entries were added. For columns that are automatically incremented you do not need to map but it is advisable to map the other columns.

```
            var table = new DataTable(); // create the datatable

            table.Columns.Add("location", typeof (string));
            table.Columns.Add("product_name", typeof (string));
            table.Columns.Add("product_id", typeof (string));
            table.Columns.Add("object_price", typeof (string));
            table.Columns.Add("session_id", typeof (string));


            foreach (var pair in webidsAndXPaths) // then loop all dictionary entries and add the rows
            {
                table.Rows.Add(location, productName, pair.Key, pair.Value, sessionId);
            }

            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                // Set up the column mappings by name.
                var l = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("location", "location");
                var pn = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("product_name", "product_name");
                var pid = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("product_id", "product_id");
                var pp = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("product_price", "product_price");
                var sid = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("session_id", "session_id");


                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(l);
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(pn);
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(pid);
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(pp);
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(sid);

                // destinationDatabase = "dbo.ObjectInventory"
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationDatabase;
                conn.Open();
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table); // write to database
                conn.Close();
            }

            return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your needs?

```
// Add a column with the correct name
table.Columns.Add("CreatedDate", typeof (DateTime));
// ...
// Update the row you are inserting
table.Rows.Add(location, productName, pair.Key, pair.Value, sessionId, DateTime.Now);
```